# Disable VSCode Extensions in user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VSCode appliance in docker with multiple pre-installed extensions.
By default the extensions get enabled when a session is created including a settings file in $HOME/.local/share/code-server/User/state/.json.
When I disable an extension in the UI the extension gets an entry in this config file meaning that it is disabled.

Is there a way to disable an extension before a session is created?
I was looking at the $HOME/.local/share/code-server/User/settings.json file but in the documentation I can't see an attribute for that.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There was an option to turn off extension for the specific project.
Unfortunately, this option is not longer available:

[image]

Feature Link(used to work):  [Ability to enable extensions only on specific workspaces #15611](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15611)